# Using WinSCP to access a remote SFTP server

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, sftp, winscp

I am using SFTP client(WinSCP) to get into a remote server and retrieve some files. I could not get to the SFTP server when I use WinSCP in a Windows-7 machine; but it works good when I try it from an XP machine. Can anyone think of what might be wrong. Any help appreciated!

I am also including the error screenshot, if that helps[image]

Can anyone please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be some problem with your firewall. Check it if you are blocking WinSCP.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting WinSCP documentation on the error message [Server unexpectedly closed network connection](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_unexpected_close):

> If you get this error message while connecting to your server, it is
>   most usually caused by the server not being able to run some process
>   necessary to support your session. Always try to connect with another
>   SSH (SFTP) client to find, if it is server or client related problem.
>
> Possibilities are:
>
> - Shell.
>
>   - Your account may not be allowed to start a shell at all. With some servers (like OpenSSH or Sun SSH), you may need to be allowed to
>       start a shell, even if using SFTP protocol.
>   - Also some servers refuse to start a shell if your password has expired or your account was terminated.
>   - Some shells do not work with non-interactive sessions. The same it true for some configurations (or profiles used) for otherwise
>       working shells. This commonly exhibits with SCP protocol with
>       associated error message "Error skipping startup message. Your shell
>       is probably incompatible with the application (BASH is recommended)."
>       Try to force bash shell explicitly on SCP/Shell page of Advanced Site
>       Settings dialog. Using SFTP protocol instead of SCP is another option.
>   - OpenSSH server may fail to start shell when chroot is configured, but not possible (e.g. due to group writeable permissions
>       to chroot directory).
>   - Some environments require specific permissions (e.g. 755) to files like .profile or .bashrc.
> - SFTP server.
>
>   - Your account may not be able to start SFTP server binary (e.g. /bin/sftp-server) or the binary is not present on your server.
>   - Your SSH server may also lack the SFTP subsystem.
> - SSH server:
>
>   - Your SSH server, particularly OpenSSH, may not be able to access the server key files, due to an incorrect permissions.